# How to Subtract Row numbers to find time passed between events

Tags: google-sheets

I'm working in google sheets and I'm trying to find a way to subtract the first time a value in a column appears (its first row number) from the last time it appears.

For example:
1    brett
2    michael
3    john
4    brett

I am trying to get it to subtract the last time brett appears (4) to the first time (1) for a result of 3. I am using this to catalogue time in my specific spreadsheet between events. I'm not sure if I'm looking in the right place for the formula, but I couldn't find it.

This is what I have right now to obtain the value, but I'm not sure where to go from here.
= VLOOKUP("Brett", A2:A105)

Answer (score 1):

To calculate the difference with the last appearance, you can try this approach in B2:

```
=BYROW(A2:A,LAMBDA(name,IF(name="","",IFERROR(ROW(name)-XMATCH(name,A1:OFFSET(name,-1,0),0,-1),"No previous"))))
```

[image]

Change "No previous" with the value you want when there's no match

Comment: `BYROW(A2:A` to `BYROW(TOCOL(A2:A,1).....` may reduce use of `IF()` function inside `LAMBDA()`.

Comment: @Harun24hr You're right, now I've checked again and see it works; but until a couple of days ago many of the new rolled formulas didn't work still in the Android app. I'm glad they do now!!

Comment: And of course it would work if there are no spaces. Since it's some kind of timetable there could be, TOCOL could not be preferable in this particular case

Comment: Google re-released those new functions on last 14-Mar-2023 permanently. Yes, in case of blank cells in middle this wouldn't be a good choice. Then `A2:INDEX(A2:A,=MATCH("zzz",A2:A))` will work. This is faster approach than `IF()` for large dataset.

Comment: Good to know they're here for good! Yes, this would narrow the processing until the last text filled cell, but without deleting the IF part if OP wants to decide how to handle empty in-between rows. (Also, there's an extra `=` before MATCH.) Thanks for the suggestions!